# How to add field variables from the HomePage to a stream StructBlock

Tags: python, django, wagtail

Hi i have a doubt around how can i show info from the model page onto a block, specifically, a structblock.

On my homepage model i have multiple charfields, where i store the link of the social media of the website, and i wish to know how can i print these links inside the template of a structblock on my streams, additionally i wish to know if this is possible too for an img, this is what i've tried so far:

home/models.py

```
class HomePage(Page):
    template = "home/home_page.html"
    landing_page_template = "home/home_page.html"

    social_media_display = BooleanField(blank=True, default=True)
    facebook_link = CharField(max_length=200, default="#")
    instagram_link = CharField(max_length=200, default="#")
    twitter_link = CharField(max_length=200, default="#")
    youtube_link = CharField(max_length=200, default="#")

    logo_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+"
    )
```

Streams/blocks.py

```
class FooterPlus(blocks.StructBlock):
    tlf = blocks.CharBlock(required=True, max_length=20, label="Tlf", default="+58")
    email = blocks.CharBlock(required=True, max_length=20, label="Email", default="")

    class Meta:
        template = "streams/parts/footer_plus.html"
        icon = "plus"
        label = "Footer plus"
```

footer_plus.html

```
<a href="{{self.facebook_link}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things. In your template footer_plus.html, `self` is the StructBlock so it won't have a facebook_link. Right now you are only storing that information on instances of the HomePage model. If you somehow put FooterPlus on your homepage instance, you could probably reference it as `page.facebook_link`.

But I think what you probably really want to do is to have those social media links available for all pages on your site so you can have a consistent footer. I would recommend you look into using Wagtail's Settings module: https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html

---

OK given that setup, I see why you have your data in the home page. What I would suggest is retrieving the data you need in a `get_context` method in your StructBlock. What I mean is something like this - but modified to retrieve the correct home page for the current requested locale:

```
def get_context(self, value, parent_context=None):
    context = super().get_context(value, parent_context)
    # Do something to figure out what homepage you need
    # The code below doesn't take into account locale so modify as needed
    site = Site.find_for_request(context['request'])
    home_page = site.root_page
    if home_page.social_media_display:
        context['facebook_link'] = home_page.facebook_link
        # etc
    return context
```

Comment: Working on multi-lingual sites, I put all these into snippets rather than site settings since Wagtail doesn't support translatable site settings.